# Application insight -> export -> Power BI Data Warehouse Architecture

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-application-insights, data-warehouse, star-schema

Our team have just recently started using Application Insights to add telemetry data to our windows desktop application. This data is sent almost exclusively in the form of events (rather than page views etc). Application Insights is useful only up to a point; to answer anything other than basic questions we are exporting to Azure storage and then using Power BI.

My question is one of data structure. We are new to analytics in general and have just been reading about star/snowflake structures for data warehousing. This looks like it might help in providing the answers we need.

My question is  quite simple: Is this the right approach? Have we over complicated things? My current feeling is that a better approach will be to pull the latest data and transform it into a SQL database of facts and dimensions for Power BI to query. Does this make sense? Is this what other people are doing? We have realised that this is more work than we initially thought.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely pursue Michael Milirud's answer, if your source product has suitable analytics you might not need a data warehouse.

Traditionally, a data warehouse has three advantages - integrating information from different data sources, both internal and external; data is cleansed and standardised across sources, and the history of change over time ensures that data is available in its historic context.

What you are describing is becoming a very common case in data warehousing, where star schemas are created for access by tools like PowerBI, Qlik or Tableau. In smaller scenarios the entire warehouse might be held in the PowerBI data engine, but larger data might need pass through queries.

In your scenario, you might be interested in some tools that appear to handle at least some of the migration of Application Insights data:

https://sesitai.codeplex.com/

https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/application-insights/app-insights-code-sample-export-telemetry-sql-database.md

Our product Ajilius automates the development of star schema data warehouses, speeding the development time to days or weeks. There are a number of other products doing a similar job, we maintain a complete list of industry [competitors](http://ajilius.com/competitors/) to help you choose.

Answer (score 2):

I would continue with Power BI - it actually has a very sophisticated and powerful data integration and modeling engine built in. Historically I've worked with SQL Server Integration Services and Analysis Services for these tasks - Power BI Desktop is superior in many aspects.  The design approaches remain consistent - star schemas etc, but you build them in-memory within PBI.  It's way more flexible and agile.

Also are you aware that AI can be connected directly to PBI Web? This connects to your AI data in minutes and gives you PBI content ready to use (dashboards, reports, datasets).  You can customize these and build new reports from the datasets.

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-content-pack-application-insights/

Comment: Yes, we've seen that. However, we 've found that we need the raw data to perform analysis, which AI only keeps for 7 days, hence the export to Azure Blob storage. 

From what you've said though, it does look like we are on the right lines. We'll build them in memory from the Azure Blobs until such a time that performance becomes an issue, which might then require us putting the queries into a SQL database.

Comment: Out of interest - can you customize these beyond what is available? It seems pretty fixed to me! How would I get my own events in there? I had hoped it would provide examples of how it is getting the data, but that all appears to be hidden.

Comment: Yes the data details are hidden in the cloud - you just get a dataset.

Answer (score 2):

What we ended up doing was not sending events from our WinForms app directly to AI but to the Azure EventHub

We then created a job that reads from the eventhub and send the data to

1. AI using the SDK
2. Blob storage for later processing
3. Azure table storage to create powerbi reports

You can of course add more destinations.

So basically all events are send to one destination and from there stored in many destinations, each for their own purposes. We definitely did not want to be restricted to 7 days of raw data and since storage is cheap and blob storage can be used in many analytics solutions of Azure and Microsoft.

The eventhub can be linked to stream analytics as well.

More information about eventhubs can be found at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-csharp-ephcs-getstarted/

Answer (score 0):

You can start using the recently released Application Insights Analytics' feature. In Application Insights we now let you write any query you would like so that you can get more insights out of your data. Analytics runs your queries in seconds, lets you filter / join / group by any possible property and you can also run these queries from Power BI.
More information can be found at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-analytics/

Comment: Unfortunately, these queries only run on raw data, which is only retained in Application Insights for about a week currently.